# C++ and Scripting.Dictionary from scrrun.dll

Tags: c++, com, scripting.dictionary

I have some trouble with Scripting.Dictionary in C++.
I'm trying to use interface IDictionary via smart pointer but methods of creating object don't work and I can't understand why.

```
CoInitialize(NULL);

IDictionaryPtr dict;
dict.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Dictionary));
_variant_t num1 = 1;
_variant_t num2 = 2;

dict->Add(&num1, &num2);

long i;
dict->get_Count(&i);
cout << i << "\n";
```

But method Add does not work and cout of elements in dictionary is always 0. How correct to use Scripting.Dictionary in that case.
PS.: I'm getting Scripting interfaces by #import "scrrun.dll"

Comment: When you call `Add()` it should return `HRESULT` - what value does it have?

Comment: Thank's for question, I found a mistake, now I'm using VARIANT and VariantInit instead of _variant_t type.